# 400 Error : origin_mismatch Google glass playground

Tags: google-mirror-api

I am getting an error when I am trying to enter client_id at Playground.
I have taken the mirror-quickstart-java-master project from google developer repository and I have followed the steps mentioned at site.
I am able to see the screen as below after mvn jetty:run
[image]

I have created the client id as below -
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: You should obscure the client id and secret.

Comment: You're mixing two different projects here, and I'm not sure if that is intentional or not. Are you setting up a Quickstart project, or trying to use the Playground to do screen designs? Or both with the same client_id?

Answer (score 0):

In your Google Developer Console, add `https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com` to the "Authorized Javascript Origins" field of your client settings (Edit Settings->Authorized Javascript Origins).

Answer (score 0):

Origin mismatch is normally caused by the Javascript origins not being set correctly in the API project console. You need to make sure that the Javascript origins match the domain from which your requests are coming and to which you are returning the user after sign in.

See similar post [Got origin_mismatch error in Google+ share api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850350/got-origin-mismatch-error-in-google-share-api)

Answer (score 0):

there is very simple solution of this error..

Just open your website or app where you want to access sign in and copy url and then paste same url in both fields i.e. redirect url and Javascript origin.