# Google Apps Script - origin_mismatch error in Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, mismatch

I'm aware there is a very similir [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850350/got-origin-mismatch-error-in-google-share-api). But this assumes that you are developing a web app on a html fle uploaded to your own server domain. **How do I need to set up the Javascript origins in the [API project console](http://developers.google.com/console) when I'm working on a Google Site?**

[image]

My Google Sites URL looks like **https://sites.google.com/a/domain-name.com/site-name/page-name**. I can't paste that URL since it says that the origin domain can't containt a path like **http://example.com/subdir**

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: origin_mismatch
>
> Application: Custom form
>
> You can email the developer of this application at:
>   my-email@my-domain.com
>
> Request Details immediate=false response_type=token
>   scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
>   redirect_uri=postmessage proxy=oauth2relay945850002
>   state=845063282|0.3789568949
>   origin=https://n-qaqvqexe4f52wy3jge4j7oquqn5qtfw3gn4sumq-script.googleusercontent.com
>   include_granted_scopes=true
>   client_id=498878908299-opvf61qsrpr6en5kvh74esqbmii1nc7u.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   authuser=0

And [this](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld) is the example code that I'm using

Comment: have you tried https://sites.google.com?  in JavaScript origin?

Comment: The documentation specifies that you should "create new key" of type "browser key" but what you have created is "client ID". Client IDs work based on callbacks or origins while keys work on referrers.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting lot of hours, adding the URL after `ss_domain=` to the Authorized JavaScript origins worked for me.

- From the error windows click on Request Details, look for `ss_domain` and copy that uri in the JavaScript Origins.