# "Error: origin_mismatch" while trying to log in with google API

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am writing a web page with java script that has a user log in button (google authorization) and it works fine with this guide: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

When I tried to upload the html page to some host (Google drive host) and try to log in I get this odd message:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: origin_mismatch

Application: MED

You can email the developer of this application at: *****@gmail.com

Request Details
response_type=token
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay541999932
state=259894099|0.2086575188
origin=https://ea071c7be2c73136e3e3e15fda8074457cacd31b-www.googledrive.com
include_granted_scopes=true
client_id=37316297355-ur11ism5dhu378pbfac7k36e3jhbn17u.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
```

What should I do to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you update the application settings in the developer console to include the new origin url? It has to match exactly.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do I need to change??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Got origin\_mismatch error in Google+ share api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850350/got-origin-mismatch-error-in-google-share-api)

Comment: Also have a look at the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/+/sign-in-faq#were_seeing_error_origin_mismatch_during_sign-in_testing_what_might_be_the_issue)

Comment: For my case, I was setting http://localhost:8000/ on the google console but  using 127.0.0.1:8000. When I changed to the localhost one it works.