# Google OAuth2 Origin Mismatch

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I want to use Google Youtube Analytics API. I know that we have to use Oauth2, so I get my client ID and then follow this instruction https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application cause I use youtube analytics for my web app.

I get confused when my request get error response

> Error: origin_mismatch
>   [image]

[image]

I have checked my **Authorized JavaScript origins**, make sure that they are same. I also host my code.

**EDIT**
just in case you wonder my code, here my index.php file

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad"></script>

</head>
</body>

    <div id="login-container" class="pre-auth">This application requires access to your YouTube account.
        Please <a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a> to continue.
    </div>
    <div class="post-auth">
        <div id="message"></div>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div>Choose a Video:</div>
        <ul id="video-list"></ul>
      </div>

<body>
```

`
Did I do something wrong???
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution myself. I just change `immediate: true` to `immediate: false` on checkAuth function. I dont know why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the OAuth ClientId you're using matches with the URI Origin you've specified in your Google Dev Console. For example you have this Client ID 1234567890 for the URI origin `http://www.mysimplesite.com` in GDC, that ClientID will only work on that domain.

If you want that Client ID to work on `http://www.myawesomesite.com` as well, you'd have to add it on the list of URIs. If you use it in a domain not specified in "Authorised Javascript origins", you will have origin mismatch error. 
[image: http://imgur.com/q2PJGCP]

Note: Make sure you've enabled Youtube API as well.

For additional reference you may check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850350/got-origin-mismatch-error-in-google-share-api) as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer before. I have double checked my GDC and I have input **Authorize Javascript origins** correctly. I found my solution myself. Thnks